# Was directory/.pm ever a convention, and why does it exist?

Tags: perl, import, module, require

[Having just figured out this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59042700/why-do-some-users-quote-classnames-in-perl), I was wondering how the `-M` would handle a terminal `::` affixed to a package name,

```
$ perl -MFoo:: -e1
```

What I got was...

> Can't locate `Foo/.pm` in `@INC` (you may need to install the `Foo::` module) (`@INC` contains: [...]).

This seems to indicate that it doesn't work, so curiosity compelled me....

```
$ mkdir Foo;
$ echo "package Foo {  sub k { die 42 }  }; 1;" > Foo/.pm
$ PERL5LIB=. perl -MFoo:: -e'Foo::->k'
```

That did in fact work. Is this convention of `use mod::;` resolving to `mod/.pm` supported? Was this a holdover from antiquity. Where did this behavior come from?

With this schema I could do,

```
Foo/.pm         # package Foo
Foo/Bar/.pm     # package Foo::Bar
Foo/Bar/Baz/.pm # package Foo::Bar::Baz;
```

then I could do

```
use Foo::;            # resolves to Foo/.pm
use Foo::Bar::;       # resolves to Foo/Bar/.pm
use Foo::Bar::Baz::;  # resolves to Foo/Bar/Baz/.pm

Foo::->new;
Foo::Bar::->new;
Foo::Bar::Baz::->new;
```

I like this because this adds the benefit of

1. Making all of my classes bare words.
2. Adding consistency between `use` and invocation.

Is this design by intent? Is it documented anywhere? Has anyone ever thought of this awesome idea before?

Comment: I'm missing how that's any better than not using the trailing :: in making your classes bare words and consistency between `use` and invocation. And I expect that if P5P ever felt that this was confusing and stripped trailing slashes they wouldn't hesitate to remove it, though I doubt there'll ever be any impetus to do anything about it.

Comment: I have a link at the top. Essentially, if you have a package called `Foo::Bar` and you invoke with `Foo::Bar->new` then if you have a `package Foo { sub Bar { "Baz" } }` you're actually doing `( Foo::Bar() )->new`, ie `"Baz"->new`. So you can do `Foo::Bar::->new` to get around this but then your `use` import is different. So amusingly you can rig `use Foo::Bar::` to work too. Then your `use` and your references to the package are the same. `use Foo::Bar::; Foo::Bar::->new`

Answer (score 8):

> *Is this convention of use mod::; resolving to mod/.pm supported?*

No.

The parser is too liberal when it comes to accepting `::`, allowing you do rather absurd things.

```
$ cat Foo/Bar.pm
package Foo::Bar;
sub import { print "imported.\n"; }
print "loaded.\n";
1

$ perl -I. -e'require Foo::Bar'
loaded.

$ perl -I. -e'require Foo::::::Bar'
loaded.
```

Using the non-canonical form leads to problems.

```
$ perl -I. -e'use Foo::Bar; use Foo::Bar; use Foo::Bar;'
loaded.
imported.
imported.
imported.

$ perl -I. -e'use Foo::::::Bar; use Foo::::::Bar; use Foo::Bar;'
loaded.
loaded.
imported.
```

Similarly, that `use Foo::Bar::` loads `Foo/Bar/.pm` shouldn't be taken as an intentional, supported feature.

> *Has anyone ever thought of this awesome idea before?*

It actually would be a mess.

For starters, you would have to use `use Foo::Bar::;` instead of `use Foo::Bar;`.

```
$ cat Foo/Bar/.pm
package Foo::Bar;
sub import { print "imported.\n"; }
sub baz { print "ok.\n"; }
1

$ perl -I. -e'use Foo::Bar;'
Can't locate Foo/Bar.pm in @INC ...

$ perl -I. -e'use Foo::Bar::;'

$
```

But using `use Foo::Bar::;` isn't enough because `import` was never called. The package directive would need to match the file name (`package Foo::Bar::`) for `import` to be called, which means you'd have to adjust qualified references to the package as well.

```
$ cat Foo/Bar/.pm
package Foo::Bar::;
sub import { print "imported.\n"; }
sub baz { print "ok.\n"; }
1

$ perl -I. -e'use strict; use Foo::Bar; Foo::Bar::baz();'
Can't locate Foo/Bar.pm in @INC ...
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.

$ perl -I. -e'use strict; use Foo::Bar::; Foo::Bar::baz();'
imported.
Undefined subroutine &Foo::Bar::baz called at -e line 1.

$ perl -I. -e'use strict; use Foo::Bar::; Foo::Bar::::baz();'
imported.
ok.
```

To put it lightly, this is undesirable.

Even if your module doesn't have an `import` method at this time, that could change, and having two different and incompatible conventions for loading modules is hurtful.

---

> *Where did this behavior come from*

While the expression `Foo::Bar::` produces the string `Foo::Bar`, `use` doesn't take an expression.

Additionally, the literal is passed to an implementation of package name to file name transliteration that performs no sanity checks. Perl simply performs an operation equivalent to calling the following sub:

```
 sub pkg_to_qfn { ( $_[0] =~ s{::}{/}gr ) . '.pm' }
```

Answer (score 1):

One minor drawback to this convention is that it breaks prior assumptions that `Foo/Bar.pm` is in `Foo/Bar.pm`. So `use` statements without the terminal `::` do not work,

```
mkdir Foo
mkdir Foo/Bar
echo "package Foo::Bar { sub baz { } } 1" > Foo/Bar/.pm

# Dies can't resolve to file,
PERL5LIB=. perl -MFoo::Bar -e1
Can't locate Foo/Bar.pm in @INC ...

# Works fine.
PERL5LIB=. perl -MFoo::Bar:: -e1
```

So the `Foo::Bar::->new` syntax is compatible with the `use` code that already worked. While changing the location of the module will break compatibility with older `use` statements, (so they would have to be updated too).

Comment: Using `Foo/Bar/.pm` doesn't just "break compatibility" with `use Foo::Bar;`, it also prevents the module's import method from being called.